# Is there a magnetic force acting on a conducting ring falling due to gravity in presence of a uniform magnetic field that exists along $-z$ direction?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction, lenz-law

If so, then why? We know that a current carrying closed loop in a uniform magnetic field experiences no force but when it's suddenly pulled by an external force, according to Lenz law a magnetic force will start acting on it to oppose the external force and eventually reach steady state at infinity. How can this be?

Edit: Iam sorry for not specifying the doubt clearly, here is the question in which I was confused as to how there can be a magnetic force acting on the ring

[image]

Comment: It might help to add a bit more detail to your question. What direction is -z in relative to the rest of the problem, and how is the ring oriented relative to the magnetic field?

Comment: If the ring is falling parallel to the field then the flux through the ring is not changing so no EMF is induced in the ring and therefore no magnetic field is produced by the ring.

Comment: Welcome Mr Mixo to Physics Stack Exchange. When saying "We know" in a question, it is always best to give a link to the source of that "knowledge". As has been noted in another comment and an answer, the premise of the question seems incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

As @JohnRennie mentioned, there is no change in the magnetic flux passing through the falling ring, and thus no emf is induced. However, it is important to consider the material of which the ring is made. For instance, if we assume that the ball is ferromagnetic, it becomes a permanent magnet in the uniform magnetic field but, as long as the magnetic field is uniform, the net magnetic force remains zero during the fall. Recall that even if the ring is left to fall oblique relative to the field lines, there is no torque that tends to rotate the ring in a specific direction. However,  all the molecular magnetic dipoles are pointed in the same direction of the external magnetic field.